# Stop btn-group wrapping buttons

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a small div that contains a bootstrap horizontal `btn-group`. The buttons are wrapping because the div is not wide enough to fit it.

How can I stop this and keep the buttons all horizontal and horizontally centred?

Problem:
[image]
How it should look:
[image]

```
<div class="vd-text-widget" style="position: absolute; background-color: #eee; width: 10%; height: 15%; left: 10%; top: 50%">

    <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg btn-group-horizontal">
        <button class="btn btn-default">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></span>
        </button>
        <button class="btn btn-default">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-header"></span>
        </button>
        <button class="btn btn-default">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-link"></span>
        </button>
        <button class="btn btn-default">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-font"></span>
        </button>
        <button class="btn btn-default">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-text-size"></span>
        </button>
    </div>

    <p>abbnnb </p>
</div>
```

**Edit:** Using `display: -moz-box` works on firefox. Will look into other browser solutions. Any ideas how to make it horizontally centred?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
 <div class="btn-group" style="display: flex">
```

Answer (score 1):

Change width to `20%`

```
style="position: absolute; background-color: #eee; width: 20%; height: 15%; left: 10%; top: 50%"
```

[Online Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jh3r88so/)

OR you can do it by change `btn-group-lg` to `btn-group-sm`

Comment: I should have clarified, the small outer div will have a variable width and height - its resizable. I want the btn-group to not wrap regardless of the widget (small outer div) dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

You could add *white-space: nowrap;* to the *.vd-text-widget* class.